# Page Inspector reporting that external files have been modified

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I am having a weird problem with Page Inspector in Visual Studio 2012.

Page Inspector works fine on any newly created ASP.NET MVC 4 project.

However, in our complex MVC project, whenever we start Page Inspector (whether running debug or not), after the web page has loaded, we get a message in black on yellow at the top of the Page Inspector window, which says:

```
Files in external projects have been modified and might impact the
current page. Click here to build the solution and refresh the
browser. (Ctrl+Alt+Enter)
```

If I do click on on the text, it pauses briefly to say "Build in progress" and then the following is displayed in the same place:

```
There were errors during the build. See the Output Window for details.
```

If I look in the Output window, there is only the normal report of a successful build.

This behavior is repeatable on different computers running the same solution. I can't think of anything obvious that has changed recently in the project that could have created this problem. The text shows up on all pages of the project, all the time.

This is a new behavior, the solution has been developed over several weeks, and I have been running the Page Inspector without problems. This message was noticed today.

We are running RTM versions of Visual Studio 2012 on 64bit Windows 8 Enterprise.

Any idea on how I could get rid of the strange Page Inspector warning? What files is it referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After experimenting with reverting to various previous versions of the source code (git is great!), I concluded that the problem started when I added a windows console application to the solution. If I exclude that project completely from the solution the problem goes away.
I still don't understand why this should be so. The MVC project does not reference the console project. Seems like a bug in Visual Studio to me.

Comment: Funny, I have the same problem and the solutin also worked for me.  Odd bug.